# error in 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02' and application get crashed

Tags: android

After adding an firebase to your applicatio,I got this error message(All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-rc02, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02 and com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0). and when i run my application it get crash. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvJnP.png)

Comment: please post your gradle dependency block , it is not completely visible in image

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear，you must use same exact same version specification, so check the build.gradle and update older version manually.

or you could click menu `Analyze -- Run inspection by Name`, and input "Newer Library Version Available" in search box. this will help you find newer library.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your build.gradle file with the following code

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'